# Proof a function is continous.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functions

Is the function $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, where $f(x_1,x_2) = x_1^2 + x_2^2$, a continuous function?

**My attempt:**

Suppose that $\forall \varepsilon > 0$ $\exists \delta >0$ such that $d((x_1,x_2),(y_1,y_2)) = \sqrt{(x_1-y_1)^2 + (x_2-y_2)^2} < \delta$. I would like show that $d(f(x_1,x_2),f(y_1,y_2)) < \varepsilon$. We have $d(f(x_1,x_2),f(y_1,y_2)) = |x_1^2 + x_2^2 - y_1^2 - y_2^2|$ and now I don't know what should I do.

I have the same problem with function $f(x_1,x_2) = x_1x_2$, because I have to show $|x_1x_2 - y_1y_2| < \varepsilon$, and again, I have no idea.

I will be grateful for any help.

Comment: It might be easier to show: 1) Polynomials are continuous, and 2) The sum of continuous functions is continuous, and then apply these results. Then, for the second part you can prove 3) The product of continuous functions is continuous. Then, you can use 1) to prove your second question.

Answer (score 1):

The function $m(x,y)=xy$ from $\Bbb R\times\Bbb R$ to $\Bbb R$ is continuous.

To show that, take $ϵ>0$ and consider the point $(x_1,y_1)$. We have $|x_1y_1-x_2y_2|=|x_1||y_1-y_2|+|y_2||x_1-x_2|$.
Now choose $\delta>0$ such that $δ<\epsilon/2|x_1|$ and $δ<ϵ/2(|y_1|+δ)$.
If $d((x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2))=|x_1-x_2|+|y_1-y_2|<δ$, then $|x_1||y_1-y_2|<|x_1|δ<ϵ/2$.
And also $|y_2||x_1-x_2|<|y_2|δ<|y_2|ϵ/2(|y_1|+δ)<ϵ/2$.
This shows that $|m(x_1,y_1)-m(x_2,y_2)|$ can be made arbitrarily small, so $m$ is continuous.

As a consequence, if $f,g:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ are continuous, then so is $f\cdot g$ as it's the composition $\Bbb R\stackrel{(f,g)}→\Bbb R×\Bbb R\stackrel*→\Bbb R$.

To prove continuity of your $f(x,y)=x^2+y^2$, you'll also need the result that $a:(x,y)↦x+y$ is continuous. I'll leave the proof to you. After that, try to write $f$ as a composition of continuous functions.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$$|x_1^2+ x_2^2 - y_1^2 - y_2^2| \leq |x_1^2 - y_1^2| + |x_2^2 - y_2^2| = |x_1+ y_1|\cdot|x_1 - y_1| + |x_2+ y_2|\cdot|x_2 - y_2|$$

and $|x_i - y_i|\leq d\big( (x_1, x_2), (y_1, y_2)\big)$.

Comment: So I have $d(f(x_1,x_2),f(y_1,y_2))  \le (|x_1+y_1|+|x_2+y_2|) \sqrt{(x_1-y_1)^2 + (x_2-y_2)^2}$ and what now?

Comment: Now given $\epsilon$, how would you choose $\delta$ such that the left hand side is smaller than $\epsilon$?

Comment: So $\delta < \frac{\epsilon}{|x_1+y_1|+|x_2+y_2|}$ ?

Comment: Yes! You are done.

Comment: Ok, but $x_i,y_i$ are variables so can I use them to find limit of  $\delta$?

Comment: You want to show that $f$ is continuous at $(x_1, x_2)$, then this point is fixed. As you assume $(y_1, y_2)$ converges to $(x_1, x_2)$, you may also assume that $(y_1, y_2)$ is bounded (say, $|y_i| \leq |x_i|+1$). Then $\delta$ can be chosen. Note that the choice of $\delta$ really depend on the point $(x_1, x_2)$.