# Continuous function - how prove?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x_1,x_2) = (\cos(x_1),x_2^2)$. Is it true that this function is continuous? What about $f(x_1,x_2) = (e^{x_1},x_2)$ ?

I suppose that these functions are continuous but I don't know how to prove it. I will grateful for your help.

Comment: $f$ should go into $\Bbb R^2$.

Comment: Can you prove that the functions $y = \cos x_1$ and $y=x_2^2$ are continuous functions? Do you know the definition of continuity for functions $f : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$?

Answer (score 1):

A function into a product space is continuous iff each coordinate is continuous. That means $\cos(x_1)$ and $x_2^2$ should depend continuously on $(x_1,x_2)$. The first can be written as $\cos\circ p_1$ where $p_1$ is the projection $(x_1,x_2)\mapsto x_1$. The second is $s∘p_2$, where $s:x↦x^2$ is the square function. Since projections are continuous, it suffices to show that $\cos$ and $s$ are.

Regarding $s$: This also follows from a [more general fact](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/560280/proof-a-function-is-continous/560312#560312). If $f,g:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ are continuous, then so is $f\cdot g$. Let $f=g=\mathrm{Id}$, and you get continuity of $s$.

Answer (score 0):

**Theorem.** Let $g,h \colon {\mathbb R} \to {\mathbb R}$ be continuous functions. Define $f \colon {\mathbb R}^2 \to {\mathbb R}^2$ by $f(x,y) = (g(x,y), h(x,y))$. Then $f$ is continuous as well.

This theorem can be used to prove that your two functions $f$ are continuous, which is much easier and more insightful than using the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition of continuity. If you don't know (the proof of) this theorem, prove this using the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition of continuity.